# "beforeunload" event not firing on Google Chrome for popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, window, addeventlistener

I need to run some code when a second window is closed by the user:

```
var win = window.open("chat-box", null, "height=600,width=1300,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");  

if(win != null)
{
    win.addEventListener("beforeunload", function()
    {
        console.log("It closed");
    });
}
```

It works in firefox, but not Google Chrome.

Any ideas on why or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

An approach I've used in the past is an interval timer to check for `win.closed`

```
if(win){
   let timer = setInterval(()=>{
       if(win.closed){
          console.log('It closed')
          clearInterval(timer)
       }
   }, 1000);
}
```